# Android ActionBar Background gets overridden by AppTheme Background

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I just can't figure this one out:
I have an application with an ActionBar, I want the ActionBar to be red and the background of the app blue. I tried to achieve this with this styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="background">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/red</item>
    <item name="background">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

But the actionBar is always blue. When I take away the blue background of the app, the actionBar is red as desired...

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this v22 of the support library?

Comment: um, I suppose it is v7, since there is `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin that you set is ambiguous and does not apply to anything. You should set the margin on your action bar theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is a red action bar with a blue background, it is much easier to use the material properties included with v21+ of the support library:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, it is not the top bar that I want red (the one you showed in darker blue here), but a new rectangle between the very top bar and the action bar.
But thank you also for this interesting information!

Comment: ... You want to add another view that goes above the action bar?

Comment: Then you would have to use a no action bar theme, create that view, and place a `Toolbar` as your action bar below it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you were trying to do... you for sure need to work on your asking skills.

Comment: This question wasn't really about the margin. It was really only about why the color did not behave the way I was expecting it to. Sorry if this was not clear!